# Rails: Are there any gems for generating sharing links (for affiliate marketing)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, share

Are there gems that can extend models as **shareables**? If an item, for example, is shareable, then each user can get an unique share URL of the item. If exists, it might acts in this way:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  act_as_shareable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  act_as_sharer
end

# Then can generate an unique share URL like this:
path = some_item.share_by(some_user).path  # "/items/1?ref=v7D3SG251a"
```

[Updated]

And the gem also generates a middleware that counts on any request with `params[:ref]` and also set the cookie of the requester.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe such solution doesn't exists (each use case will be different, so there is no universal gem). However you can build it using an existing gem:

- https://github.com/alexlevin/rack-affiliates

Comment: Thank you! But I wonder if it can be universalized. Would you say more about different use cases? I am considering to write a gem like this. (I also update my question.)

Comment: You need to generate reflinks, have controllers to support them and they all depends on structure of your app. So here I see most problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct - rack-affiliates will catch any ?ref= in the URL and store it in a cookie.  Nothing to do with shareable, though.  Just tell your affiliates to use ?ref= to get credit for the sale, or generate a share url with their ref id.

Edit: The ?ref= is changeable to some other parameter if that's what you would like.

Comment: Yeah. But with db records, a gem can track how many people visit the link. And the gem can also try to detect crawlers from social medias to determine if the link has really been shared.